# Least common multiple in Euclidean algorithm

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm, euclidean-algorithm

I want to prove that in last step of Euclidean algorithm we have lcm representation 
(by last step I mean the step with zero representation as $0 = x * E_0 + y * E_1$, where we apply euclidean algorithm for $E_0$ and $E_1$) 
I can proof that statement $lcm(E_0, E_1) = |x * E_0| = |y * E_1| $ is equivalent to the statement that $gcd(x, y) = 1$ 
I can proof that we can consider only cases with $gcd(E_0, E_1) = 1$ 
I know that $x * y = lcm(x, y) * gcd(x, y)$ 
I also know that $lcm(x, y) = |x * E_0| = |y * E_1|$ (since $gcd(E_0, E_1) = 1$) 
And here I stuck. I only can get some obvious relation like $E_0 = \frac{y}{gcd(x, y)}$ and $E_1 = \frac{x}{gcd(x, y)}$ 
Or, equivalently, $y = E_0 * gcd(x, y)$, $x = E_1 * gcd(x, y)$ (calculations up to sign, we can chose representation with $x \gt 0$ and omit all modules)
 
I thought we can prove more strong statement, i.e. on every step of euclidean algorithm, when we have representation $E_r = x_r * E_0 + y_r * E_1$, we always have $gcd(x_r, y_r) = 1$ and tried to prove it by induction, but there were too many variables 
I suppose there should exist an easier way to prove it, but I can`t find it

Comment: Do you want a proof of something or simply a means of finding LCM?

Answer (score 1):

First, you find the GCD of two terms then multiply each term by the other-divided-by-GCD.
For example $$x_1=10\quad\land\quad X_2=35\implies GCD(x_1,x_2)=5$$
$$LCM(x_1,x_2)=x_2\times\frac{x_1}{GCD(x_1,x_2)}=35\times\frac{10}{5}=70$$
or
$$LCM(x_1,x_2)=x_1\times\frac{x_2}{GCD(x_1,x_2)}=10\times\frac{35}{5}=70$$
or
$$LCM(x_1,x_2)=\frac{x_1\times x_2}{GCD(x_1,x_2)}=\frac{350}{5}=70$$

The algorithm for finding GCD is expressed in this simple [BASIC] program

```
 100 input i1
 110 input i2
 120 x1 = i1
 130 x2 = i2
 140 r1 = x1 mod x2
 150 c1 = c1+1
 160 if r1 > 0
 170    x1 = x2
 180    x2 = r1
 190    goto 140
 200 endif
 210 print "iterations( "  c1 ")",;
 220 print "GCD( " i1 ", " i2 ") = " x2
```